# Char, AnsiChar, PChar, PAnsiChar ?

Tags: delphi, dll, char

This Code is copied directly from the website commitcrm.com
It is a demostration on how to use their API ( Like Hello World, it **connects** to an database, **creates** an account, and **update** that account )

It compiles **perfect** on Windows XP + Delphi 2007 and the executable works **perfect**.

If the exact same code is compiled on Windows 7 + Delphi XE2/XE5/XE7 then executable gives error :(

I have found that it is somehow **related** to Char / Ansichar, pChar / PAnsiChar.

Because, when I **change** the char to ansichar for the CmtInitDbEngDll procedure, it actually connect to the database. Great.

But I am not able to (I am not good enough) find out what I have to change...should it be char, ansichar, pchar, pansichar and so on, because I am not sure how to handle it when a DLL is involved.

Is there any smart delphi people who can help ?

------  SOURCE CODE   ----------------------------------------------------

```
program Demo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

const
 C_DataBuffSize = 1024;
 C_MapBufSize = 1024;
 C_ErrMsgBuffSize = 1024;
 C_DescSize = 1024;
 C_ErrCodeBuffSize = 64;
 C_RecIDBuffSize = 64;

 C_Flag = 1;
 C_Ok = 1;
 C_AccountsTable = 10;
 C_AppName = 'Demo';

 CmtDbEngDll = 'C:\CommitCRM\ThirdParty\UserDev\CmtDbEng.DLL';

var
 Status: integer;
 DataBuff: array [0..C_DataBuffSize] of Char;
 MapBuff: array [0..C_MapBufSize] of Char;
 RecIdBuff: array [0..C_RecIDBuffSize] of Char;
 ErrCodesBuff: array [0..C_ErrCodeBuffSize] of Char;
 ErrMsgBuff: array [0..C_ErrMsgBuffSize] of Char;
 s: string;

//** Establishing connection with CommitCRM, Should be called only once for the entire session *
Procedure CmtInitDbEngDll (
             xSoftWareName   : PChar; // Your application name. Once selected this  string
                                      // will be used for all
                                      // functions of the package. Specify a meaningful value.
             xDbPath         : PChar; // Path to the DB folder under where CommitCRM server is
                                      // installed <server>\CommitCRM\Db

             var xvStatus     : integer           // Returned connection status
            ); stdcall; external CmtDbEngDll;

//**** Insert/Update record
Procedure CmtInsUpdRec(
             xSoftWareName   : pChar;            // See above
             xDataKind           : integer;      // Desired Table Code
             xDataBuff           : pChar;        // String containing the values, which we want
                                                 // to add into the Database
             xMapBuff            : pChar;        // List of the database fields into
                                                 //which we want to add data
             xContWhenInvalidData : Integer;     //Flag - stop(0)/continue(1) the input process
                                                 // is some data value(s) is invalid
             xFlags                : Integer;              // Not used
             xRecIDBuffLen      : Integer;          // Length of REC ID Buffer
             xLogErrCodesBuffLen  : Integer;  // Length of Error Code Buffer
             xLogErrMsgBuffLen     : Integer;     // Length of Error Message Buffer
             xvRecIDBuff          : pChar;            // Buffer for returned REC ID
             xvErrCodesLogBuff : pChar;         // Buffer for returned Error Codes
             xvErrMsgLogBuff    : pChar;         // Buffer for returned Error Messages
              var xvStatus       : Integer          // Returned status
             ); stdcall; external CmtDbEngDll;

//**** Terminate connection with CommitCRM ****
procedure CmtTerminateDbEngDll; stdcall; external CmtDbEngDll;

procedure CmtGetDescriptionByCode(
                                 xCode     : Integer;
                                 xDescLen  : Integer;
                                 xvDesc    : pChar); stdcall; external CmtDbEngDll;

procedure CmtGetDescriptionByStatus(
                                   xCode     : Integer;
                                   xDescLen  : Integer;
                                   xvDesc    : pChar); stdcall; external CmtDbEngDll;

procedure ErrCodesParsing (ErrCodeBuff: string);
var
 lList: TStringList;
 i: integer;
 aDescErrCode : Pchar;
begin
 try
   lList := TStringList.Create;
   lList.Text := ErrCodeBuff;
   GetMem(aDescErrCode,C_DescSize);
   for i := 0 to lList.Count - 1 do
   begin
     CmtGetDescriptionByCode(StrToInt(lList[i]), C_DescSize, aDescErrCode);
     writeln('Error Code: '+lList[i]+' Desc: '+string(aDescErrCode));
   end;
 finally
   FreeMem(aDescErrCode);
   lList.Destroy;
 end;
end;

procedure DisplayErrStatusCode(xCode : Integer);
var
 aStatusErrCode : Pchar;
begin
 try
   GetMem(aStatusErrCode,C_DescSize);
   CmtGetDescriptionByStatus(xCode,C_DescSize, aStatusErrCode);
   writeln('Commit Init failed. Error code: '+Inttostr(xCode)+' Desc: '+string(aStatusErrCode));
 finally
   FreeMem(aStatusErrCode);
 end;
end;

begin

 //**** Establishing connection with CommitCRM, Should be called only once for the entire session
 CmtInitDbEngDll(C_AppName, // Your application name. Once selected this string will be used
                            // for all functions of the package. Specify a meaningful value.
  'C:\CommitCRM\Db\',                    // Path to the DB folder under where CommitCRM server is
                                          // installed <server>\CommitCRM\Db
  Status                   // Returned connection status
   );

 if Status = C_Ok then
 begin

   //**** Insert a new Account into the Accounts table ****

   s := '"Bart De Hantsetters","De Hantsetters","Hantsetters"';
   StrPCopy(DataBuff, s);
   s := '"'+#13','+#13+'FLDCRDFULLNAME'+#13+'FLDCRDDEAR'+#13+'FLDCRDCONTACT'+#0;
   StrPCopy(MapBuff, s);

    CmtInsUpdRec(C_AppName,         // Your application name
                 C_AccountsTable,   // Desired Table Code
                 DataBuff,          // String containing the values, which we want to add into
                                    // the Database
                 MapBuff,           // List of the Database Fields in which we want to add data
                 C_Flag,            // Flag - stop(0)/continue(1) the input process is some data
                                    // value(s) is invalid
                 0,                             // Not used
                 C_RecIDBuffSize,         // Llength of REC ID Buffer
                 C_ErrCodeBuffSize,      // Length of Error Code Buffer
                 C_ErrMsgBuffSize,       // Length of Error Message Buffer
                 RecIdBuff,                 // Buffer for returned REC ID
                 ErrCodesBuff,             // Buffer for returned Error Codes
                 ErrMsgBuff,                // Buffer for returned Error Messages
                 Status                      // Returned status
         );



   if (ErrMsgBuff[0] <> #0) then
     writeln('Error Message: '+ ErrMsgBuff);

   ErrCodesParsing(ErrCodesBuff);

   if Status = C_Ok then
   begin
 //**** Updating the Account record we've just created *****

     // Map file for the update transaction - the Dear field and the record id
     s := '"'+#13+','+#13+'FLDCRDDEAR'+#13'FLDCRDRECID';
     StrPCopy(MapBuff, s);

     s := '"Doctor","'+RecIdBuff+'"';
     StrPCopy(DataBuff, s);

     CmtInsUpdRec(C_AppName,           // Your application name
                  C_AccountsTable,     // Desired Table Code
                  DataBuff,            // String containing  the values, which we want
                                       // to add into the Database
                  MapBuff,             // List of the database fields into which we want to add
                                       //data
                  C_Flag,              // Flag - stop(0)/continue(1) the input process is some
                                       // data value(s) is invalid
                  0,                   // Not used
                  C_RecIDBuffSize,     // Length of REC ID Buffer
                  C_ErrCodeBuffSize,   // Length of Error Code Buffer
                  C_ErrMsgBuffSize,    // Length of Error Message Buffer
                  RecIdBuff,           // Buffer for returned RECID
                  ErrCodesBuff,        // Buffer for returned Error Codes
                  ErrMsgBuff,          // Buffer for returned Error Messages
                  Status               // Returned status
         );

     if ((ErrMsgBuff[0] <> #0)) then
       writeln('Error Message: '+ ErrMsgBuff);

     ErrCodesParsing(ErrCodesBuff);

     if Status = C_Ok then
       Writeln('Completed Successfully');
   end
   else
   begin
     try
       s := IntToStr(Status);
     except
       s := 'ill-defined';
     end;
     writeln('Insert new Account. Error code: '+ s);
   end;

 //**** Terminate connection with CommitCRM****

   CmtTerminateDbEngDll();
 end
 else
 begin
   DisplayErrStatusCode(Status);
 end;

 writeln(#13#10+'press Enter to quit');
 readln;
end.
```

Comment: Did you read any documentation concerning Unicode Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Delphi up to and including Delphi 2007 was basically 8-bit ANSI.  Delphi 2009 and later are Unicode.

Here are two links that might help:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio
- http://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf

> Embarcadero introduced full Unicode support in RAD Studio for the
>   first time in August of
>   2008. In doing so, they ensured that Delphi an d C++Builder would remain at the forefront of native application development on the Wind
>   ows platform for a very long time to come.
>
> However, unlike many of the
>   other major enhancements that have been introduced in Delphi over the
>   years, such as variants and interfaces (Delphi 3), frames (Delphi 5),
>   function inlining and nested classes (Delphi 2005) and generics (RAD
>   Studio 2009), enabling Unicode didn't involve simply adding new
>   features to what was already supported in Delphi. Instead, it involved
>   a radical change to several fundamental data types that appear in
>   nearly every Delphi application. Specifically, the definitions for the
>   String, Char, and PChar types changed.
>
> These changes were not adopted
>   lightly. Instead, they were introduced only after extensive
>   consideration for the impact that these changes would have for
>   existing applications as well as how they would affect future
>   development. In addition, Embarcadero sought the input and advice of
>   many of its Technology Partners who support and promote Delphi.
>
> In reality, there was no way to implement the Unicode support without
>   some inconvenience.
>   ...
>
> The String type is now defined by the UnicodeString type, which is a 
>   UTF-16 string. Similarly, Char type is now WideChar, a two-byte
>   character type, and PChar is a PWideChar, a pointer to a two-byte
>   Char.
>
> The significant point about the changes to these basic data types is
>   that, at a minimum, each character is represented by at least one code
>   unit (two bytes), and sometimes more.